# Struggling with commands in Xterm

Tags: command-line, kernel

I am absolutely struggling with the cp command and the moment and I would like to know where to just learn all the usefull commands. Like cp HAS to start at /home right? 
I also hate that I cant just manually copy the file to /var/www any help in making it easier for me? My options are: learning the commands till I can dream about it or just easily do everything like windows, like copying etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visit this site for reference: [Command Line Learning Resources](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandLineResources)

Well, it spurts out file not found because the file test.php must be located in another location. Well if you do not want to read huge tutorials and do it the easy way, type this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gksudo
```

Then run:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

gksudo will grant nautilus root priveleges after you type in the password in the pop up. You will then be able to copy paste the files anywhere easily. It is just that vulnerable files are located in placed other than the home directory, altering which may lead to an unusable system. Hence this extra step must be taken, i.e. giving root privileges using the command sudo. Also note that nautilus should be replaced with thunar, dolphin, pcmanfm in case you are using xubuntu, kubuntu, or lubuntu respectively.

Comment: Will this work for /var/www as well?

Comment: Yes it will, it will give you root privileges, i.e. you can do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Nautilus file manager to copy files. That should be on your launcher. You don't have to use the terminal.

Comment: This wont work for /var/www everytime it's complaining about not enough permission